# Is healing blade nerfed too like all other life steal?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am thinking of trying this build:
http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4551608970

However, I've heard that life steal is nerfed by 80% in inferno.

Does that affect healing blades?

Comment: All life steal is nerfed in Inferno.  http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/game-difficulty#life-steal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effectiveness of the **Life Steal** affix – which restores your Life by a percentage of the damage you deal – is reduced in advanced difficulties, as shown:

**Normal:** 100%

**Nightmare:** 70%

**Hell:** 40%

**Inferno:** 20%

Keep in mind, however, that Life on Hit items are still perfectly viable in any difficulty. It's very common for the monk and barbarian to have high LoH (1500+) just to survive Act 3/4 inferno.

[Diablo 3 Life Steal Entry](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/game-difficulty#life-steal)

Comment: Both answers are correct. This one is more detailed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all skills which provide life steal are subject to the same effectiveness reduction based on difficulty that is applied to life steal provided by items.

Comment: any references?